# How to unpack a tarball with npm to get the package.json file out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have ran the npm pack command to pack the project (a react app) into a tarball. I can see inside it that the package.json still exists, but when i run npm install on the tarball then i only get a package-lock.json file out which means i can't run things like npm start that is defined in the package.json. Am I missing a step out here? I can't seem to see anything on the following documentation page https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-documentation/

Comment: "but when i run npm install on the tarball" -> that comment makes it sound like you are running install within the compressed file.

Comment: no, running npm install tarball.tgz inside the folder where the tgz is

Answer (score 2):

Tarball is a compressed file format. You need to unpack it before running the npm command.

From: http://www.rebol.com/docs/unpack-tar-gz.html

To unpack a tar.gz file, you can use the tar command from the shell. Here's an example:

`tar -xzf rebol.tar.gz`

Then inside the directory that is unpacked. You can `npm i`

As Peter pointed out in the comment -> npm and tar are different resources.

As always - dont forget to approve the answer and upvote if you liked my answer and it helped. Thanks!

Comment: To further clarify, `npm` as a tool isn't made to unpack tarballs. You need to use the separate `tar` tool that comes installed on most unix systems before you can use any `npm` commands on it.

Comment: hmm ok, trying to figure out the best way to package up the project for releasing. (clearly new to this). I thought i would need to zip up the project, extract it in the desired location and then run npm start to begin running the app?? I could be way off what the recommended approach is?

Comment: There could be a number of answers to that. How were you planning on releasing your project? Is it a website you created that you have a server ready to host it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=mMFRXImIHMegtQW11KH4Dw&q=continuous+deployment+tools&oq=continuous+deployment+tools&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8.787.2407..2464...0.0..0.168.550.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67.mvuDYLuZH4A ... I am a HUGE fan of deployment tools. I recommend spending time researching different ways of releasing projects.

Comment: i will be using teamcity and octopus, and there is a server ready

Comment: I apologize but I am not very familiar with that tool. I did find their docs though: https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications

Comment: I don't understand this answer; `npm` most assuredly *can* install from a `.tgz` file. That is, `npm install something-1.2.3.tgz` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking in the wrong spot.

```
$ npm i my-package.tgz
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<...>/testdir/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<...>/testdir/package.json'
npm WARN testdir No description
npm WARN testdir No repository field.
npm WARN testdir No README data
npm WARN testdir No license field.

+ my-package@0.0.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.711s
$ ls
node_modules package-lock.json
$ ls node_modules/my-package
<...> package.json <...>
$ node_modules/.bin/<your executable> <args>
```

When you `npm install` something, it *always* goes into `node_modules` in your local `npm` project. If you want to run an executable, you'll access it through `node_modules/.bin`.

If you want something installed so you can run it anywhere, use `npm i -g` and ensure that the global `npm` `bin` directory is on your path.